# At-home routine to balance rock climbing

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, home-exercise, rock-climbing

I'm looking to improve my at-home body-weight training routine. It's a kind of circular training I've devised to balance my rock climbing. Climbers who don't do complementary training end up with over developed back, sunken chest and bad posture.

My goal is to stretch and strengthen the rest of the body with different kind of exercise. That includes major muscle groups in the core, chest, abs, arms and legs. Key part of this routine is to avoid gripping and pulling anything because that's what climbing is for.

The routine is as follows (not including warm up and stretching):

1. 10 push-ups with high legs, 10 squats
2. repeat
3. 20 crunches, 20 calf raises
4. repeat
5. 5 pistols each leg, 10 "1.5 push-ups"
6. repeat

I cycle this 3 times with 1 minute pauses between each number. Is this ok or am I actually counter productive?

Comment: If you're able to do pistol squats, why are you doing regular squats?

Comment: It feels good to stretch my back with regular squats. But good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described above is similar to what I do for my antagonist training for bouldering. I do recommend adding something like supermans, the ones where you lay on your stomach and lift your shoulders, head, arms, and feet off the ground, these will build the muscles that climbers neglect in the back. I would also recommend training the antagonist muscles to your grip. This will help protect your elbows as you progress in climbing. I do this personally using a rice bucket but you could use a rubber band or something else. The main thing is you are trying to train your strength for opening your hands.